# How to Hide or disable the webview top corner icon in android weview

Tags: java, android, kotlin, webview, pdf-viewer

I am using to webview loading pdf file in webview. I am facing an issue where the webview is showing a top side corner icon. I want to disable or hide this icon. I also need a zoom in and zoom out option. Can you please help me resolve this issue? I have attached a snap for your reference and i have attached my code as well.

```
 class PdfViewer : AppCompatActivity() {
    private val LOADER_ID = 1

    // private val pdfView: PDFView by lazy { findViewById(R.id.pdfView) }
    private var progressViewBar: ProgressBar? = null

    override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
        setContentView(R.layout.pdf_viewer)
        val webView: WebView = findViewById(R.id.webView)
        window.setFlags(
            WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_SECURE,
            WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_SECURE
        )


        // Get the PDF URL from the intent
        val pdfUrl ="https://home.uchicago.edu/~jcarlsen/2007/downloads/Selections.pdf"
        // Ensure that the PDF URL is not null
        if (!pdfUrl.isNullOrBlank()) {
            // Enable JavaScript (required for PDF.js)
            webView.settings.javaScriptEnabled = true
            webView.settings.builtInZoomControls = true
            //  webView.settings.displayZoomControls=false
            webView.webViewClient = WebViewClient()

            try {
                val encode_url =
                    URLEncoder.encode(pdfUrl, "UTF-8") //Url
                webView.loadUrl("https://docs.google.com/viewerng/viewer?embedded=true&url=" + encode_url);
// Convert to UTF-8 It important.
            } catch (e: UnsupportedEncodingException) {
                e.printStackTrace()
            }

            // Load the PDF viewer HTML file with the dynamic PDF URL
        } else {
            // Handle case where PDF URL is null
        }
    }

}
```

[image]

Comment: i have added my code, please help.